# Solving a Polynomial Function Given 3 Zeros, 1 Having a Square Root

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have not been taught how to do this and I'm stumped on a problem. I found similar questions but I'd like to be sure of the correct answer.
The problem reads: Give a polynomial function that has the zeros $0$, $1$, and $3-\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: There's double root, $3+\sqrt{5}$ is solution too

Comment: I didn't know that played in. Thank you so much! Hopefully I get it.. CX

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is $$x(x-1)(x-(3-\sqrt{5}))$$ but this will have non rational coefficients. If these are the only roots then you are done. If you want rational coefficients then take $$x(x-1)(x-(3-\sqrt{5}))(x-(3+\sqrt{5}))$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'm currently in high school and seeing all of the geniuses here is somewhat intimidating... I hope to become as smart as you one day!

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for you to work through the steps of this problem? I'm having trouble understanding how you got to that point. This problem was thrown to me out of the blue and I'm terribly sorry for troubling you with it.

Comment: These guys are not geniuses. Dont be fooled by illusions.

Comment: Its just that $(x-a)(x-b)$ etc has roots $a,b$ maybe work out tge second example to see why the coefficients are rational.

Comment: Maybe not geniuses, but definitely a heck of a lot smarter than me! I just found a video with an explanation, but it gave 2 radical roots. Is it given that because 5 is square rooted, that it is both positive and negative despite the problem listing one?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus you're right, I'm just a grade 11 schoolstudent.